# Can't find Fusion Log Viewer Windows Server 2012 Visual Studio 2013

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

It's really all right there in the question. This is the first time I've heard of Fusion Log viewer but it sounds like it can help me solve my problem. All the documentation says it's really easy to start, all I have to do is: 
- Type 'Fusion' in my Start menu 
- Search for 'fuslogvw.exe' or type 'fuslogvw' in Administrator command prompts 
- Do something with Developer Command prompt, which I also cannot find on Windows Server 2012 
- Change a Registry setting 
 
I have tried all these things (except changing the registry setting, because I can't find that setting and I don't screw with regedit if I can at all help it) and cannot find the program. I see where I can download it, but according to Microsoft if I have VS installed I already have it.

Please do not refer me to this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx or this one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859(v=vs.110).aspx because neither of them tells me how to do this in Windows Server 2012.  
 
To be specific I have: 
Windows Server 2012 (running in a VMWare Virtual Machine on a Mac, though I don't see how that matters) 
Visual Studio 2013 
 
Where is this program, or do I just not have it and have to download it?

Comment: Okay, I see how it works. I created the ForceLog setting and a LogPath and now it's dumping all my data into the log path. Thanks!

Comment: don't use the use fusion log any longer, sue ETW instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29374658/1466046

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- fuslogvw is shipped with [.NET Framework Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9kh6s92(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Set HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion\ForceLog setting to 1 is one of the necessary step, as I remember. I see, that you don't have it, so just create new DWORD one.
- fuslogvw can be run from from Visual Studio Command Prompt.